# Spotfire function to pick rows based on custom condition

Tags: spotfire

The sample data table image is attached, the sample data shows we have two locations and two type of meter and two different dates and 5 hours of data. Need to generate a table which can differentiate between the parameters mentioned above and provide with a table to show for when to when the power was showing 0 sample output table is also present in the image.[image]